# Getting Null Context when trying to retrieve PackageInfo

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

Spent the entire day on this but can't get it to work.

I'm trying to create an app drawer.
I want get a list of currently installed applications and then put it in an GridLayout.

I'm getting a nullPointerException when I try to call `getPackageManager` from a class that extends my MainActivity.

InstalledApp class:

```
public class InstalledApp extends MainActivity {
Context context = this;

public InstalledApp(Context c) {
    this.context = c;
}

class PInfo {
    public String appname = "";
    public String pname = "";
    public String versionName = "";
    public int versionCode = 0;
    public Drawable icon;
    public void prettyPrint() {
        System.out.println(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

public ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */ //Line 29
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0); //line 39
    for( int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++ ) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        InstalledApp.PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

In MainActivity:

```
InstalledApp installedApp = new InstalledApp(this);
    ArrayList<InstalledApp.PInfo> pInfoArrayList = installedApp.getPackages(); //Line 73
    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, pInfoArrayList);
    gridLayout.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Log cat:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageManager(ContextWrapper.java:90)
        at squaredem.materiallauncher.InstalledApp.getInstalledApps(InstalledApp.java:39)
        at squaredem.materiallauncher.InstalledApp.getPackages(InstalledApp.java:29)
        at squaredem.materiallauncher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:73)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why your some InstalledApp class helper for getting packages is extending activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating **InstalledApp installedApp = new InstalledApp(this);** installedApp object which is extending Activity, but this activity is not created by the system but by you. So this InstalledApp object does not have **Context** object bounded to system.

Invoke of `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);` is possible because MainActivity extending Context, but its null...

Better does not extend MainActivity with InstalledApp. And use  `context. getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);` context field which you pass in InstalledApp constructor

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just create a subclass of `Activity`, create an instance of it manually, and expect it to work.

Move the `getPackages()` and `getInstalledApps()` methods into `MainActivity`, and you will have better luck.